# Ecto create unique index with nulls

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to create a unique index with an ecto migration for a PostgresDB.

```
def change do

  create table(:categories) do
    add(:name, :string)
    add(:parent_id, references(:categories), null: true)
    timestamps()
  end

  create(index(:categories, [:parent_id]))

  create(
    unique_index(:categories, [:name, :parent_id], name: :unique_categories_name_parent_id)
  )
end
```

However, this does not work when the `parent_id` is `NULL`. I know that PostgresSQL 15 supports `NULLS NOT DISTINCT` but my db is on v13.
This there a way to ensure unique name field with NULL parent_id here?

Comment: Maybe you could try with raw sql in migration for creating index with NULL values, if it works then maybe just add up and down functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create additional partial index for the case when the `parent_id IS NULL`:

```
create unique_index(:categories, [:name], where: "parent_id IS NULL")
```

This will create partial index for you that will check if the `name` field is unique only if `parent_id IS NULL`.